# Is my CPU broken or my motherboard?

Tags: cpu, motherboard, power-supply, hardware-failure

I've built my first computer nearly 2 years ago and have been using it fine ever since. A couple of days ago, I was installing a new SSD. I turned on the PC and it didn't recognize the new drive, so I unplugged and reconnected all cables and rebooted.

As soon as I hit the power button I heard a loud bang accompanied with a bright blue flash from the back of my case. The PSU had blown. Being foolish and in a state of shock I unplugged, reconnected and tried again; PSU blown again.

Great, now I had double the chances of everything being fried. I decided to stop destroying my computer and order a new PSU. I connected it, crossed my fingers, turned on the PC and...
Nothing.

I've tested as much as I can in another computer and it turns out the GPU, SSD and RAM still work. I'm assuming the HDD still works as the SSD does, but I'm not sure about the CPU. When the computer is turned on, I get a single static LED on the motherboard, but no fans are spinning.

The motherboard is still getting power and supplying power to its outputs; monitors flash with 'no signal' message when connected. Unfortunately, I have no other AM3+ sockets to test the CPU, so is there anyway I can tell if the motherboard or CPU has gone?

I still don't know what caused it, wether it be static or just the bad PSU (Amazon reviews show similar cases of my PSU blowing up).

Comment: At your own risk you can try finding other compatible PSU and try turning the machine with it, but the chances are pretty high (based on your description) that you've fried both CPU and motherboard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No one will be able to tell you for certainty without trying, but it is orders of magnitude more likely that the problem is with the motherboard then the CPU.

For a start, motherboards have caps that go "bang", CPU's don't (I imagine you would notice the hole and physical damage to a CPU as well)

For another thing, motherboards have filtering and power control circuitry on them - it is this circuitry which is most likely to have taken the hit.

Comment: This answer, though educated guesswork, has the added advantage of it being a solution that starts with the cheaper component.

Comment: Bought another motherboard and PSU and it works! Still an expensive fix, but lucky that it was only those two components. Thanks for the help!